# Laravel sidebar navigation links not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

Hi I am trying to build a default layout in my laravel app, I am building a button that when clicked it shows a menu. Even though the icon is not appearing, when I click on the space it should be in nothing is happening. It is supposed a sidebar opens with some links. Here is my code:

app.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Human Resources') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Human Resources') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" class="d-none">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
        @if(Auth::check())
            @if(Auth::user()->is_admin == 1)
            <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- Sidebar -->
                <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                 <!-- Page Content -->
                <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <a href="#" class="btn" id="menu-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></a>
                                    @yield('content')
                            </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            @endif
        @endif
            
        @guest
            @yield('content')
        @endguest
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuDisplayed");
        });
    });
</script>
```

css

```
/* Sidebar */
#sidebar-wrapper{
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
    width:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background: #5b4282;
    opacity:0.9;
      transition:all .5s;
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
  }
  
  /* Main Content */
  #page-content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;    
    position: absolute;
    padding:15px;
      transition:all .5s;
  }
  
  #menu-toggle{
      transition:all .3s;
      font-size:2em;
  }
  /* Change the width of the sidebar to display it*/
  #wrapper.menuDisplayed #sidebar-wrapper{
    width:250px;
  }
  
  #wrapper.menuDisplayed #page-content-wrapper{
    padding-left:250px;
  }
  
  /* Sidebar styling */
  .sidebar-nav{
    padding:0;
    list-style:none; 
      transition:all .5s;
      width:100%;
      text-align:center;
  }
  
  .sidebar-nav li{
    line-height:40px;  
      width:100%;
      transition:all .3s;
      padding:10px;
  }
  
  .sidebar-nav li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ddd;
  }
  
  .sidebar-nav li:hover{
    background:#846bab;
  }
```

Comment: Please show what the compiled HTML of your menu is showing. This is not Laravel issue YET, but a HTML/JS.

Comment: Does not show any error , when button is clicked nothing happens

Comment: That we already read in your initial question. Show your effort on how YOU tried to solve the issue with the menu not showing when button is clicked.. Right now you re expecting us to just write out the code for you? With no effort shown?

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Just do it and try once and I hope you will get some help.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```